# Validation email with TLD in Angular 1.2

Tags: angularjs

Angular has changed their validation rule for emails in 1.2

Email's such as me@host are considered valid.

How can change the validation rule so that only addresses such as me@host.com are considered valid and me@host would be invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal regex function to validate like this:

```
var validateEmail = function(email) {
          var emailReg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
          return emailReg.test(email);
        };
```